# What would the "correct" way be to fire 900 people at once?

Tags: termination

In the news, last days Better.com and their CEO have received a lot of criticism for firing 900 people (10% of their staff) at once over a video call. Immediately after the meeting, the fired employees had their computers frozen, probably due to concerns from the company.

As mentioned, I see a lot of criticism, but I wonder how a company should have handled this given limited resources, remote work, and concerns over stealing from fired employees? Or did Better.com act correctly?

Comment: You are concerned that the fired employees will become ninjas? Odd phrasing of that second-to-last sentence...

Comment: I can't think of any way to fire 10% of your staff without people getting upset. You're going to get criticism no matter what you do.

Comment: A company with 9000 employees has "limited resources"?

Comment: @sf02 I mean, in an ideal world every employee would get a visit from an HR person giving them the bad news. The resources for that are not available.

Comment: @MLEN, in any mass lay-off I've ever been through, the affected people were at least told in a private meeting with their manager. Everyone has a manager, right?

Comment: @SethR The sounds reasonable, I have never been through any mass lay-off so that is why I am asking.

Comment: @MLEN How do you know the resources were not available?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: There are 20 crummy ways of doing this and on good one. Pick your poison

Comment: Following the WARN act procedures  and best HR/IR practice

Comment: I believe this could be made on topic by asking **"What is the normal way to fire 900 people from a company?"**. That's pretty easy to answer.

Comment: You certainly can do it with advance notice rather than just locking them out of their computers and immediately dismissing them. You're not going to shut down a factory or warehouse overnight, for instance. See e.g. [this article](https://qz.com/work/1663731/mass-layoffs-a-history-of-cost-cuts-and-psychological-tolls/)

Comment: This question is being [discussed](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7016/should-questions-about-problems-that-someone-other-than-the-op-faces-be-allowed) on Meta.

Answer (score -8):

One person's opinion (this is in no way an "expert opinion" and should not be taken as such):

Firstly, it's hard to fire 10% of your company without a bit of backlash.  That's a lot of people out of work, and, although it's cliche to say, "during a pandemic" (although personally speaking I've received more job interview requests as an engineer in the past couple months than I received for years prior to covid; I get 2-3 per day almost every day, so the "during a pandemic" line is fairly overstated, to me anyway).  Additionally, the problem is less the scale of people but, as you correctly pointed out, the number of people.  A 10-person startup firing one worker is losing 10% of their workforce which is the same as here (by scale), but not every small startup makes top-news headlines when they cut a person; as you correctly pointed out, the fact that it was 900 people is the important part here, so that's also noteworthy.

Another noteworthy point is that, according to a cursory Google check, [the CEO of Better.com is worth approximately $4 billion (yes BILLION) dollars](https://marketrealist.com/p/vishal-garg-net-worth/).  Of course, it's big news in the media when an ultra-rich person cuts low-tier (for lack of a better term) workers; it sounds like "well what if he just cut $1B of his net worth and paid all those people instead, he can afford it".  That's a narrative the media likes to push.  So here, we have an ultra-rich CEO who took livelihoods away from 900 middle-class people.  This falls into the "rich people pay their fair share" narrative which, for better or for worse, exists.  This is another reason why the media doesn't like this story, although there's really no "good way" to handle this situation given the circumstances.

Noteworthy also is that one of the things Vishal Garg said when he fired these people is that some were only working 2 hours per day and getting paid for 8.  Which is probably true; it's in fact almost certainly true, I would bet any amount of money that there exists a plural number of people (i.e. more than 1) in the group that was fired which was guilty of this.  That said, at least in the media portrayal of the story (as much as I've been following it, which is not much), he seemed to paint a large swath of that group with that wide brush, and that's not good.  That said, I also don't have his metrics so I don't know what he based that claim off of, nor do I know what was actually said in the meeting so the media could be misreporting (which happens quite a lot, particularly in recent years).  That said, if people are finding out about this story reading biased reporting, of course they're going to react in the way that the story's bias imports them to do, that's why media bias exists in the first place.  So, I don't know whether or not the story was biased, but in any case, the way it was presented to the average layman is fairly inflammatory, as it paints the CEO as painting his employees as lazy freeloaders (which some of them probably were, but most of them "probably" (in quotes because I have no factual basis for this statement) were not), and that's not fair.  Couple this with the above claim that the CEO himself is worth $4B, and the common media notion that CEOs don't do anything and just play golf all day in their giant mansions and fly private jets, and are themselves "freeloaders" on the work of their employees, and you have yourself not only an insulting jerk, but a hypocrite as well.  Again, not that any of these portrayals are fair in the least (any of them that I've listed so far, at all), but it's important to recognize that they exist.

On top of all of the above, you also have the fact that this was done via Zoom.  There's an old adage that, if you're going to break up with a significant other, the most insulting way to break up is on the phone, or, worse, by text message.  Now, personally speaking, I have no idea why that is; at least if someone breaks up with me by text then I can forget their face and delete their contact info right there and then, while if it happens face to face then...what, I'm supposed to argue?  I dunno, but anyway, some people have this notion (I don't share it, but again it's important to recognize that it exists).  Analogically, these people were being "fired over the phone", so to speak.  The notion is that the company didn't have the "humanity", so to speak, to fire them in person, to say that they're fired, "to their face", such as it is.  Speaking as someone who was fired by waking up one morning and simply randomly being locked out of all my accounts (and receiving a phone call 2 hours later), I can't say I really care how these people are fired, but some people do, and they're upset about it because it feels "inhumane" or "disrespectful" in some way.  The "correct" way to do it, I suppose, would be to call them into the office and fire them in person, I guess?  Although, "during a pandemic" and so on, most of these people are probably working remotely, might not be near an office, and so on, plus firing 900 people one by one is exhausting for the person having those meetings, so I can understand why it was done.

Anyway, I'm not really sure if this answers the question.  To simplify all of the above, I think the answer is, there is no good way of firing 900 people without significant public backlash, particularly if you're a CEO who is worth $4B and the people you are firing are middle-class, combined with being in the middle of a pandemic when most, if not all, of your business offices are closed or at reduced capacity.  Above are some of the issues that people are considering when they are getting upset about this story, maybe that provides some context.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. Big companies cut large numbers of people very often, which hardly ever leads to backlash like this (of course often enough there is backlash, but not on this scale).

Comment: "Anyway, I'm not really sure if this answers the question. " - trust your feelings...